# Ant Design - How can i get count of table row after filtering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I use Table component from Ant-design to search, filtering and sort a big set of data but I have a problem with "Select all Data".

For example if I click on checkbox on top of table, only display rows on screen are selected. So if I change of page, the others rows aren't selected. If I want select all data I need to custom selection and use `rowSelection.selections`.

As you can see on this example extract from [ant.design website](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection-custom) below,
the proposal solution is to write directly all keys of row that I need to select, but if I have filtered just before one column I can't know the state of my props datasource.

So my question is: How can I know all the data currently available on the screen?

For example, If there is 10 pages initially, and then I filter and sort, and now there is 2 pages, how get the array of new set of data.

Thanks in advance.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedRowKeys: [], // Check here to configure the default column
  };

  onSelectChange = (selectedRowKeys) => {
    console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', selectedRowKeys);
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedRowKeys } = this.state;
    const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys,
      onChange: this.onSelectChange,
      hideDefaultSelections: true,
      selections: [{
        key: 'all-data',
        text: 'Select All Data',
        onSelect: () => {
          this.setState({
            selectedRowKeys: [...Array(46).keys()], // 0...45
          });
        },
      }, {
        key: 'odd',
        text: 'Select Odd Row',
        onSelect: (changableRowKeys) => {
          let newSelectedRowKeys = [];
          newSelectedRowKeys = changableRowKeys.filter((key, index) => {
            if (index % 2 !== 0) {
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          });
          this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: newSelectedRowKeys });
        },
      }, {
        key: 'even',
        text: 'Select Even Row',
        onSelect: (changableRowKeys) => {
          let newSelectedRowKeys = [];
          newSelectedRowKeys = changableRowKeys.filter((key, index) => {
            if (index % 2 !== 0) {
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          });
          this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: newSelectedRowKeys });
        },
      }],
      onSelection: this.onSelection,
    };
    return (
      <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this props on `Table`

`onChange: Callback executed when pagination, filters or sorter is changed`

`Function(pagination, filters, sorter, extra: { currentDataSource: [] })`

The `currentDataSource` might be the thing you want.

Comment: That's the way to control paginations and filtes in my cas, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally set pagination to false to prevent it from giving you only the total count for only the current page.

```
<Table 
     pagination={false}
     footer={(currentPageData) => {
        // console.log(currentPageData);
        return <span>{currentPageData.length}</span>;
}}>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers above to be a bit unclear. In the code below `total` will be the row count AFTER filters are applied. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
  const [tableCount, setTableCount] = useState<number>(0);
      <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={datasource}
          css={iterationTableStyle}
          pagination={{
            position: ['bottomCenter'],
            showTotal: (total, range) => {
              setTableCount(total); // store the total count in a hook
              return ``; // return an empty string unless you want to show it next to the pagination
            },
          }}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
```